# C#/.Net Execute a .cmd file

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a cmd file, lets call it myfile.cmd, that starts a program when run. I want to write a method along the lines of

```
private static void RunMyFile(pass something){ //code}
```

That when called and passed the file or the file's location and executes the file, I've been messing around with the Process and ProcessStartInfo classes but can't seem to get it to execute

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: "I've been messing around with the Process and ProcessStartInfo classes..." - can you show us what you've tried and what didn't work? You'll likely get more help that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Process.Start(filename);
```

Should do what you need.